# Vb script appears at the end of my html code

Tags: php, html, vbscript, svchost

Iam just opened my vs code and then appears script at the end of html tag, that a many numbers in there, i've tried to delete that but it reappears after some time.
[vb script that appears in html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9Fd.png)

I tried to delete it and it just appears again and again

Answer (score 0):

That's a virus.

There is an inbuilt anti-virus that comes with Windows.

1. Open your Start Menu
2. Search for "Windows Security" and open it
3. Click "Virus & threat protection"
4. Run a Full Scan (there is a Quick Scan option, ignore that)

This is your first line of defense before heading to other solutions.

Adding link to a related topic that has other solutions that you can try if this one does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31256924/17985195